# Python logging won't write to file when I prepend on path to file name

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

Recently setup some logging on a new program I'm writing.  I'm using a config file (logging.conf) to configure it and then calling it using logging.config.fileConfig().  It was working fine logging to console but I also wanted to start writing to a log file.  Made the necessary updates and it worked.  Then I noticed my log files were in the application working directory.  No big deal; I had neglected to prepend the log file name with the path to the logs directory.  Once I did that it refused to generate a file or write to it.  No idea why.  I put in a logger statement to output the path to the logfile and it's valid.  If I remove the path it writes to the program directory again.  Any ideas?

Here's how I'm invoking logging.conf:

```
working_dir = "/app_2/TSM_data_collector"
log_dir = working_dir + "/logs"
raw_data_dir = working_dir + "/rawdata"
clean_data_dir = working_dir + "/cleandata"

log_file_name = log_dir + "/" + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d') + "_tsm_orchestrator.log"
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', defaults={'logfilename': log_file_name})
logger = logging.getLogger('TSM_orchestrator')
```

Here's the contents of logging.conf:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,TSM_orchestrator

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=baseFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_TSM_orchestrator]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler, fileHandler
qualname=TSM_orchestrator
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=baseFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=baseFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s','a')


[formatter_baseFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s,%(name)s,%(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Comment: When I delete the logs/ directory Python does complain that the path doesn't exist.  So that tells me it is at least trying to write to that location but for some reason isn't actually doing it.

Comment: I tried 'hard coding' the path instead of building it dynamically and that didn't work either.

log_file_name = "/app_2/TSM_data_collector/logs/tsm_orchestrator.log"

Comment: If I print out the logger.debug(str(logger.handlers)) I can see the filename and path is correct:

2023-02-09 10:39:20,DEBUG,TSM_orchestrator,[<StreamHandler <stdout> (DEBUG)>, <FileHandler /app_2/TSM_data_collector/logs/2023-02-09_tsm_orchestrator.log (DEBUG)>]

Comment: Do you have the rights to create a file in `/app_2`? Does `/app_2` exist? If you try to create a file yourself with this path, does it work? I mean `mkdir -p /app_2/TSM_data_collector/logs` and then, in Python, `with open("/app_2/TSM_data_collector/logs/2023-02-09_tsm_orchestrator.log", "w") as f: f.write("foobar")`

Comment: @vvvvv Yes, that filesystem exists.  Yes, I can create a file in there.  Your code worked flawlessly.  

Another development:  Had a coworker try the same method and it worked on his laptop.  There's definitely something up with either my system or my environment.  

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Finally figured it out!

I had to move all the logging config code down below `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out...

I had to move all of this:

```
working_dir = "/app_2/TSM_data_collector"
log_dir = working_dir + "/logs"
raw_data_dir = working_dir + "/rawdata"
clean_data_dir = working_dir + "/cleandata"

log_file_name = log_dir + "/" + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d') + "_tsm_orchestrator.log"
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', defaults={'logfilename': log_file_name})
logger = logging.getLogger('TSM_orchestrator')
```

Below this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I never thought to even try this because in the past I did my own logging and opened the logging file up above `__main__` and just below the import statements which always worked.  Thought of trying this today and it finally writes to the log file.

Why would it work for logging to the console when the config was up above `__main__` ?  If I didn't put on any path it would write to a file just fine in the main app directory.  Even with the pathing; if I deleted the ../logs/ folder it would cry about the folder missing.
However I could never get it to actually write output to a file in the ../logs/ directory.  Feels like a bug to me but I'll pin it on ignorance on my behalf for now =^.^=